# while scrolling of uitableview the images are not loaded using sdwebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

I'm doing an assignment where i need to show the images(that is posters of movies) on uitableview in each cell.I'm getting array of urls for image using JSON Parsing.I'm trying to display on uitableview cell.But for first 60 movies it shows properly with images but after when i scroll down it gives me an exception.I'm using `SDWebImage` framework as follows. I've imported `#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    // Configure the cell...

    tableViewCellClass *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.movieNameLabel.text = [finalTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.movieNameLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.releasedDateLabel.text = [finalReleasedDateArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *urlForimageDisplay = [finalImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
    [manager downloadWithURL:urlForimageDisplay options:0 progress:^(NSUInteger receivedSize,long long expectedSize) {}
    completed:^(UIImage *image,NSError *error,SDImageCacheType cacheType,BOOL finished){
        if (image) {
            cell.movieImage.image = image;

        }
        else{
        }
    }];


    NSString *populartyNumberLabelTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",    [finalPopularityNumberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    cell.populartyNumberLabel.text = populartyNumberLabelTextString;
                         NSString *numberOfUsersLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[finalNumberOfUsersArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    cell.numberOfUsersLabel.text = numberOfUsersLabelText;
    return cell;
    [tableView reloadData];
}




-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

                         CGPoint offset= scrollView.contentOffset;
                         CGRect bounds = scrollView.bounds;
                         CGSize size = scrollView.contentSize;
                         UIEdgeInsets inset = scrollView.contentInset;
                         float y = offset.y + bounds.size.height - inset.bottom;
                         float h = size.height;
                         float reload_distance = 0;
                              if (y >= h + reload_distance) {
                                                               pageNumber = pageNumber + 1;
                                                               NSLog(@"CURRENT PAGE NUMBER %d",pageNumber);
                                                               [self loadData:pageNumber];
}
```

This is the method (`[self loadData:pageNumber]`) where i'm taking the JSON values for key posterpath that is populating the array. It gives exception as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01aa65e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018298b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01a58bcc -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 844
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01a58870 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
    4   customizedCellTable                 0x000032e5 -[tableViewClass loadData:] + 3029
    5   customizedCellTable                 0x00004643 -[tableViewClass scrollViewDidScroll:] + 467
    6   UIKit                               0x0062395b -[UIScrollView(UIScrollViewInternal) _notifyDidScroll] + 62
    7   UIKit                               0x0060dc43 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 734
    8   UIKit                               0x0067f1d1 -[UITableView setContentOffset:] + 314
    9   UIKit                               0x0061ead2 -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollWithUpdateTime:] + 4009
    10  UIKit                               0x0061eda9 -[UIScrollView _smoothScrollDisplayLink:] + 222
    11  QuartzCore                          0x03b5db8a _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEv + 48
    12  QuartzCore                          0x03b5da46 _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 310
    13  QuartzCore                          0x03b5df6b _ZN2CA7Display16TimerDisplayLink8callbackEP16__CFRunLoopTimerPv + 123
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x01a64bd6 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 22
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x01a645bd __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1181
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x01a4c628 __CFRunLoopRun + 1816
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x01a4bac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01a4b8db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    19  GraphicsServices                    0x039fb9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x039fb809 GSEventRun + 104
    21  UIKit                               0x00597d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    22  customizedCellTable                 0x00005fdd main + 141
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x023c4725 start + 0
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm new to iphone development.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let me just point out that you should not be reloading your table at cellforRowatIndexPath -  **[tableview reload]** is a trigger to call a series of tableview delegate methods including cellforRowatIndexpath (which is executed for each row in the table - so if you have 100 rows - this gets executed 100x) , coding that call in that place should result in a loop, **[This could be your exception, although this seems to be a very common mistake that Apple may have coded handlers for this kind of error]**!

I find nothing wrong with your scrollViewdidscroll since it is just collecting data without doing anything else and your [loaddata Pagenumber] is not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably elsewhere, see the stack trace. Your error says what the problem is

> *** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

It follows `scrollViewDidScroll` and then `loadData`, where it goes internal (Read the trace backwards, that is upwards).
So look for `insertObject` in that method, and at one point the first parameter you're passing it is nil. Since you didn't post that code, this how much I can help. Get back if you need more help.

Z.

Answer (score 0):

```
        __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
        __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = yourImageView;

        [yourImageView sd_setImageWithURL:"your image url here..."
                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"]
                                  options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload
                                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                                     if (!activityIndicator) {
                                         [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray]];
                                         activityIndicator.center = weakImageView.center;
                                         [activityIndicator startAnimating];
                                     }
                                 }
                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

                                    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
                                    activityIndicator = nil;
                                }];
```